# My answer got me -15 points! Why?

Tags: support, down-votes, reputation, accepted-answer

[My answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/686093) got me -15 points. Was the OP booted off the site, or what?

I am just wondering.

Answer (score 11):

The user accepted your answer on Jan 1 at 22:15 (UK time), giving you +15 points, then today they changed their mind and unaccepted the answer so you got a -15 point reversal. Overall your net rep became just the +10 from the single upvote.

If you look in [your reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/40292/niels-nielsen?tab=reputation) you'll see the -15 reversal is labelled *unaccept*.